# How click on the "Edit" button on any line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the edit button in any row. 
For example, I would like to click on the edit button the record with 777DDD in it.

Below is the HTML source of the "Edit" button:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped js-dataTable-full-pagination dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_5" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_5_info">
    <thead>..</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr role="row" class="odd">..</tr>
      <tr role="row" class="odd">..</tr>
      <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="font-w600 sorting_1">Müzakereli</td>
        <td>26/01/2018 00:00</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs"></td>
        <td>777DDD</td>
        <td class="text-center">..</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Meeting"><i class="si si-globe"></i></button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Also add problem description

Comment: I tried to format your code correctly in order to see what you are doing, but gave up after 2 minutes of reformatting, because it's way too much. Please reformat the HTML yourself. Also, provide a minimal example, not everything you have.

Comment: I edited my code. I am sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: @Seval, my answer is solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the *edit* button with the record *777DDD* in it you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-striped js-dataTable-full-pagination dataTable no-footer' and starts-with(@id,'DataTables_Table_')]//tbody//tr[@class='odd' and @role='row']//td[contains(.,'777DDD')]//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-default' and @data-original-title='Edit']/i[@class='fa fa-pencil']")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB but i get error " Unable to locate element"

Comment: Updated my Answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Unfortunately, i get error again " Unable to locate element"

Comment: Can you paste the full error stack trace either here in the comments or within the question please?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this where I'm likely going to reuse this code, I would wrap this in a function.

```
public static void clickEdit(String record)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[.='" + record + "']/following-sibling::td//button[@data-original-title='Edit']")).click();
}
```

and call it like

```
clickEdit("777DDD");
```

What you are attempting to do can only be done with an XPath (unless you want to loop and look for the desired text amongst all the records) in a single locator. The XPath above looks for a `TD` that contains the desired record name and then finds the sibling `TD` that has the Edit button and clicks on it.

---

From your comments, you seem to be getting a lot of errors around locating the elements. Make sure that this HTML is not inside an `IFRAME`. If it is, you will need to switch into the `IFRAME` before you can access the Edit button.

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this code to see if it does your work,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@id='DataTables_Table_5']//tr[3]//td[@text='777DDD']//button[@data-original-title='Edit']")).click();
```

Also like 'JeffC' mentioned, you might want to see if there are any `iFrame` in your code. In which case you'll need to `switchTo` to it first.